# SharePoint Branding Divs and PlaceHolderMain

Tags: branding

I am designing a custom master page, and have a few questions I cant see answered..

Do I wrap my container DIV around the placeholdermain like this;

```
<!-- Masterpage stuff -->
<div class="container">
<asp:Content  ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
  <!-- Page Layout -->
   <div class="container">
   <!-- page content, web part zones, web parts etc -->
   </div> <!-- End Page Layout -->
</asp:Content>
</div>
```

OR inside the placeholder like this;

```
<asp:Content  ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
 <div class="container">
   <!-- Content goes here -->
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

And do the same rules apply when applying bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `container` should be outside `Main`. During rendering the actual content will get inserted inside `Main`.

Yes the same rule applies to BootStrap.

Use https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/ as a starting point.

Comment: Hi Amal, thank you!

Another question then.  My masterpage has a Main ph, but my page layout does also, is this correct?  And does my container go outside the Main in the masterpage, or in the page layout, or both?

And in the masterpage if I wrap a container div and a row div around Main, do I just use rows and columns inside the page layout, or more containers and rows?